# How do I get my custom fields to only show when something is written in them - Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Im working on customizing a Wordpress theme with some custom fields. For this I'm using the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields", but I want it to display these fields ONLY IF something is written in them. This is the code I'm using to display the custom fields:

```
<p class="tittelboks">Artikkelforfatter:</p>
        <?php if( get_field('artikkelforfatter') )
        {
        echo '<p>' . get_field('artikkelforfatter') . '</p>';
        } ?>
```

How do I change the code so that it only echos the information AND the label (in this case .tittelboks) if something is written in the meta boxes?

Michael

Comment: Take a look at this page.

It may help you.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130195/wordpress-custom-fields-for-custom-post-types>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php if( $field = get_field('artikkelforfatter') ): ?>
    <p class="tittelboks">Artikkelforfatter:</p>
    <p><?php echo $field; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is a different way of doing an if statement, so you don't have to enclose your HTML in quotes and worry about escaping. The two lines in the middle will only print out if `get_field('artikkelforfatter')` returns a value or true. That value will be assigned to the `$field` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$artikkel = get_field( 'artikkelforfatter' );

if ( ! empty( $artikkel ) ) {
?>
<p class="tittelboks">Artikkelforfatter:</p>
<p><?php echo $artikkel; ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't work, it won't show at all.. Tried doing `if ( empty` as well and it showed, but then it showed wether it was empty or not..

Answer (score 0):

To use and display custom fields need you may try to put this in your loop.

```
<?php $what_name_you_want=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Your Custom Field Name',true); ?>

    <?php echo $what_name_you_want; ?>// This call the value of custom field
```

Only replace

> what_name_you_want with your favorite name

and

> Your Custom Field Name with the name of custom field

If the value of custom field is empty the echo will be empty to.

Tell me if it's work