# Wordpress Custom Fields for Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

This issue has arisen for several people in the past but the solutions for their issues have not worked for me and I have tried alot!

In Wordpress I have created 3 custom post types. 1 for 'videos', 'news' and 'music' and each of these post to their own page. I want to add custom fields so I can have 'artist' 'year of release' 'featuring' and 'about the album' for the music posts for instance.

I have installed Advanced Custom Fields and I can add custom fields to each of these so when the user clicks 'add new' the fields are visible. But the issue I have is that the output of these fields is not displaying on the site when I visit the page.

I created news.php, music.php and videos.php from the single.php file with the following:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: music Page
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=music'); ?>
<?php the_meta(); ?> 
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content',  get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And in functions.php I have the following:

```
/*---------music Custom Post Types---------------------------------*/

function my_custom_post_music() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'music', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'music', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New music' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit music' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New music' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All music' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View music' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search music' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No music found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No music found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Music'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our music and music specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,

    );
    register_post_type( 'music', $args );   
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_music' );



function my_taxonomies_music() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'music Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'music Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search music Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All music Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent music Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent music Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit music Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update music Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New music Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New music Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'music Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'music_category', 'music', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_music', 0 );


/*---------news Custom Post Types---------------------------------*/

function my_custom_post_news() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'news', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'news', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New news' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit news' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New news' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All news' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View news' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search news' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No news found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No news found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'News'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our news and news specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );    
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_news' );
```

Does anyone know what I am missing to get this working or what I need to do.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: <?php the_meta(); ?> in the post loop http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: Thanks Tamil - I have read through that to see how to fix it and I have added <?php the_meta(); ?> to my post loop but I still seem to be having no luck. Is there something else I'm missing or is possible I;m putting it in the wrong place or something?

Comment: which file u modified

Comment: I stuck it in news.php. I've updated the code above to show

Comment: put the <?php the_meta(); ?> in while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the value of custom fields in your loop you can use this snippet of code:

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=music'); ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php get_template_part( 'content',  get_post_format() ); ?>

   <?php $what_name_you_want=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Your Custom Field Name',true); ?>

    <?php echo $what_name_you_want; ?>// This call the value of custom field


                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Tell me if it works!

Comment: FYI Advanced Custom Fields comes with it's own functions for grabbing the values of custom fields. You should check out the documentation:http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/

`$field_value = get_field('field_name');` is nice and succinct though it does the same work as what @5wordpressthemes suggests.

Comment: Thanks Bredon I'll check that out because I'm running into several problems using advanced custom fields. I can't for instance, use the shortcode for vimeo or bandcamp in any of my fields and I can't work out why so hopefully that can shed some light on it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Output the custom field data from ACF with.

```
the_field('the-field-name');
```

get_field('the-field-name') is used for conditionals ex if (get_field('my-field'):  etc. You can also print the contents using

```
echo get_field('the-field-name');
```

I would say that your issue with Vimeo shortcodes and Custom Fields might be related to the plugin wasent built to run thru custom fields. It might be that it only checks thru the_contents() for the shortcode.