# How to add custom fields in custom theme

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Ive been searching a lot for this answer but cant work it out.

I created two custom fields for pages and posts:
one for background image, and one for background color.

Then I called the changes in my head like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
$image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background-image', true);
$bgcolor = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background-color', true);?>

#wrapper {    background-image: url('<?php echo $image ?>');
background-size: 100% auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor ?>;
}
</style>

</head>`
```

I dont want to create the custom fields in every site I use this theme so I want to add the custom fields to the theme (coded).
How can I add it to my functions.php or page.php or wherever it must be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this inside loop??

Of course yes, since you are using `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background-image', true);` and this way you are trying to execute server side code to update client side code.   I don't know which one is executed first, but I just want to trigger such a question in your mind to introduce you my approach.

I think you should think of using jQuery to manage such issue:

The idea:

- get value of custom field server side and put it as a variable attribute (a class or id or whatever attribute) of your background div.
- create external jQuery file that will listen to the document and change the CSS properties based on the retrieved attribute. I am sure there are function with jQuery that manages CSS.
  Use a plugin like `More fields` to manage easily your custom fields and avoid too much coding.

Second, it is really not good to put inline CSS in your code, the optimum way is to call external CSS files. This rule is also valid for JS scripts.

The most important thing is to know how to separate server side with client side. Good luck

Comment: Thanks but I didnt get it :$ sorry! The thing I need is to add some code to my theme, to declare the custom fields without the need to add them in wordpress admin. I know that this site already has them because I added them but I want to know the workaround to code the custom fields and display them in a clean install of wp, just install my theme and have them in my posts/pages. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find your answer:

[Wordpress Custom Fields for Custom Post Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130195/wordpress-custom-fields-for-custom-post-types/16130467#16130467)

Or you here:

http://5wpthemes.com/blog/adding-and-displaying-custom-fields-and-values-in-wordpress/

Comment: Im sorry but I think you didnt quite get the issue here. I already created custom fields and display them. But I want to be able to do one thing: add this custom fields to my theme without the need to add them manually because...those custom fields get saved in the database right? not in my code... If I use this theme in other database, I wont have the custom fields. I want to register/declare them in my theme. Not display them, I already have that in my theme.